# How to get aggregated data for a particular day in spark structured streaming

Tags: spark-structured-streaming, spark-streaming-kafka

i have one spark structured steaming job that read streams from kafka and write output to HDFS.
My issue is i need an aggregated results for the entire day till particular time.
Since spark structured streaming doesn't support complete/update mode, is there nay way to achieve same?

if i get data 10.00 AM , i need an aggregated result till 10.00 AM for the current date...

can some one help how to achieve same ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I get the exact specific of the situation, but let me try to answer.

I would recommend doing a 2-step process:

1. Spark streaming saves mini-batches to a temporary folder of format:

`/yyy-mm-dd/<offset from the day start>.parquet`

`2019-02-06/100000.parquet`, `2019-02-06/200000.parquet`

2. Another spark job reads from the corresponding location and do the aggregation and time filtering.

You can use library like [luigi](https://github.com/spotify/luigi) to manage these.